# How can I disable touchscreen while using Wayland?

Tags: gnome, touchscreen, wayland

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.  My touchscreen is glitchey; I think it is a hardware issue.  I can disable my touchscreen when logged into Gnome using Xorg, but I can't figure it out when I login using Wayland.   Any advise?  Thanks! - Josh

Answer (score 22):

Following steps in JNixus' answer on reddit gave me the result: touchscreen is disabled and touchpad still works: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/76jm9x/dell_xps_9343_linux_wayland_touchscreen_help/

Using the ability to disable a single USB device, we need just to create a UDEV rule. Create the file in

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/80-touchscreen.rules
```

With following information

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="20d0", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

You can find `idVendor` and `idProduct` by running

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

You can reload the rules without restart

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. Dell XPS 13 Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: This did not work for me (Dell XPS13, Ubuntu 18.04). Could you explain how you recognize the touch screen in the devices list ?

Comment: worked for inspiron 15 series on fedora as well

Comment: Worked on a Lenovo Thinkpad T480s with Debian Buster

Comment: I'm running Neon/KDE on some kind of Dell and while nothing seemed to be affected after running the reload command, the touch-screen is disabled after restarting.

Comment: does disabling in udev also prevent power consumption?

Comment: This works, although when I wanted to get the touchscreen back seemed like I had to reboot; just setting authorized to "1" and reload/trigger command didn't work. If anyone knows how to do that without reboot would much appreciate.

Comment: Works on a DELL Latitude XT2 with ATTRS{idVendor}=="1b96" and  ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001" (Ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: Worked on a Lenovo T490 with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @fffred In my case the device was called "ELAN Touchscreen`

Comment: do you know if it is possible (or what would be needed) to keep the stylus running while disabling touch?

Answer (score 6):

The hid_multitouch solution above disables all multitouch devices if there are multiple. But the udev route is an issue if your device isn't USB (I think). So what worked for me is to unbind the device from the driver, instead of unloading the whole driver.

You can find the devices linked to the hid-multitouch driver with

```
ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/
```

That will show a couple of files and folders, but the actual device id's are a combination of characters and numbers like this: `0018:06CB:19AC.0001`.

You may have multiple devices in there. I just figured out the right one with trial and error. Once you know, you can unbind it from the driver with:

```
echo "0018:06CB:19AC.0001">  /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
```

That will (temporarily) disable the driver. Then you could use rc-local or a dedicated systemd service to make it permanent. You can't do it in `.bashrc` or similar user space scripts since you need to be root to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The power of Google to the rescue.  I followed the instructions from  [here](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2016/10/26/disable-touchscreen-linux/) and I was able to blacklist the touchscreen driver. As per the instructions, I created a file called `hid_multitouch.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d`.

Inside the file I put:

```
# Use the following syntax
# blacklist driver-name
blacklist hid_multitouch
```

Save, restart, and no more glitchy touchscreen.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me on a samsung 940X laptop with ubuntu 17.10 and wayland -- thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, on my Dell XPS13 it disabled the touchpad as well as the touchscreen. :(

Comment: oh, maybe it didn't actually.

Comment: Also on my XPS13, it disables the touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was this startup script suggestion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/n9qu3f/how_to_disable_touchscreen_on_debian_wayland/).  I didn't like the "manualness" of the script so I added it to be more generic.  This may not work for everyone since it unbinds all hid-multitouch devices found.  Add it to the crontab as suggested in the link and this happens on boot.  **Tested on kubuntu 22.04.**

```
#!/bin/bash
for X in `find /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch -type l`; do 
  if [[ $(udevadm info ${X}|grep "DRIVER=hid-multitouch") ]]; then
    basename ${X} | sudo tee  /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For those with i2c touchscreen (like Dell Inspiron 9550), the right udev rule to use is:

```
$ sudo su
# cat>/etc/udev/rules.d/80-touchscreen-dis.rules<<EOF
ACTION=="bind", SUBSYSTEM=="hid", ENV{HID_ID}=="0018:000004F3:000029E2", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'basename $DEVPATH > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind'"
EOF
# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
# echo "0018:04F3:29E2.0002" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
# echo "0018:04F3:29E2.0002" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/bind
Ctrl + D
```

The magic number `0018:04F3:29E2.0002` in the command above is found by listing the devices in `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/` (see @dolf-andringa answer above).

The `HID_ID` is found by running the unbind/bind combo while  `udevadm monitor -u -p` is running.

The rule is generic enough to find the instance number to unbind by itself.

EDIT: Thanks for @zelitomas to report the error in the linked code

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on my Microsoft Surface Pro 3 with broken screen.
I have tested all above solutions. Many thanks to the contributors.

The one that works for me at EACH boot on my Manjaro with GNOME under Wayland:

1. You need `sudo` without password. Add the following `disable_touchscreen` script somewhere in your `$PATH`, like `~/.local/bin`:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   for X in `find /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch -type l`; do
     if [[ $(udevadm info ${X}|grep "HID_PHYS=i2c-NTRG0001:01") ]]; then
       basename ${X} | sudo tee  /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
     fi
   done
   ```
2. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/.local/bin/disable_touchscreen
   ```
3. Add a desktop entry like `disable_touchscreen.desktop` to `~/.config/autostart`:

   ```bash
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Disable touchscreen
   GenericName=Disable touchscreen
   Comment=Disable broken touchscreen
   Exec=/home/belr/.local/bin/disable_touchscreen
   Icon=/home/belr/.local/share/icons/laptop-touchscreen-128x128.png
   NoDisplay=true
   Type=Application
   Categories=System;
   NotShowIn=KDE;XFCE;
   ```

That's it !
HID multi-touch driver will be unbinded at each start : no ghost entries anymore

Comment: What do you mean *"You need `sudo` without password"* in step 1?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog you need the ability to run sudo commands without providing your password : see [here](https://linuxconfig.org/configure-sudo-without-password-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Followed the instructions on the linked [article](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2016/10/26/disable-touchscreen-linux/) above. The solution did not work however there is a helpful comment by user [Raphael](https://raphaklaus.com/) that got the touchscreen **disabled** and touchpad **enabled** for me.

Steps:

1) Edit `/etc/rc.local`

2) Add the following line `modprobe -r usbhid`

3) Save and restart

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is obsolete **since 1983**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the non-hacky way to disable the touchscreen indefinitely on a Dell Inspiron 15 3535 running Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland (fully demonstrated):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~$ sudo su - root
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 

root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/
0018:27C6:0D43.0004  0018:2A94:A811.0005  bind  module  new_id  uevent  unbind

root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# echo "0018:27C6:0D43.0004" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
```

Whoops! My trackpad no longer works. Let's undo, and try disabling the other device.

```
root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# echo "0018:27C6:0D43.0004" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/bind

root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# echo "0018:2A94:A811.0005" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
```

Voilà! The touchscreen is disabled! Now we know what device we're looking to disable. Let's reenable it so when we disable it indefinitely, we can verify that it's disabled due to our config change.

```
root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# echo "0018:2A94:A811.0005" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/bind

root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1100f02902000 8380307cf910f001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0f/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="PS/2 Generic Mouse"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse3 event7 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1bcf Product=28d3 Version=2471
N: Name="Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate"
P: Phys=usb-0000:03:00.4-4/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.1/sound/card0/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Dell WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/9DBB5994-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=800000000000 0 0 101500b00000c00 1200300000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=27c6 Product=0d43 Version=0100
N: Name="DELL0C38:01 27C6:0D43 Mouse"
P: Phys=i2c-DELL0C38:01
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-DELL0C38:01/0018:27C6:0D43.0004/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=27c6 Product=0d43 Version=0100
N: Name="DELL0C38:01 27C6:0D43 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-DELL0C38:01
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-DELL0C38:01/0018:27C6:0D43.0004/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event10 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Headphone Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=2a94 Product=a811 Version=0100
N: Name="GGT7503:00 2A94:A811"
P: Phys=i2c-GGT7503:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-GGT7503:00/0018:2A94:A811.0005/input/input20
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event5 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20

root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# udevadm info -a -p /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-GGT7503:00/0018:2A94:A811.0005/input/input20
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-GGT7503:00/0018:2A94:A811.0005/input/input20':
    KERNEL=="input20"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{capabilities/abs}=="260800000000003"
    ATTR{capabilities/ev}=="1b"
    ATTR{capabilities/ff}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/key}=="400 0 0 0 0 0"
    ATTR{capabilities/led}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/msc}=="20"
    ATTR{capabilities/rel}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/snd}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/sw}=="0"
    ATTR{id/bustype}=="0018"
    ATTR{id/product}=="a811"
    ATTR{id/vendor}=="2a94"
    ATTR{id/version}=="0100"
    ATTR{inhibited}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="GGT7503:00 2A94:A811"
    ATTR{phys}=="i2c-GGT7503:00"
    ATTR{power/async}=="disabled"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTR{properties}=="2"
    ATTR{uniq}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-GGT7503:00/0018:2A94:A811.0005':
    KERNELS=="0018:2A94:A811.0005"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-multitouch"
    ATTRS{country}=="00"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="334864"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-GGT7503:00':
    KERNELS=="i2c-GGT7503:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="i2c"
    DRIVERS=="i2c_hid_acpi"
    ATTRS{name}=="GGT7503:00"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0':
    KERNELS=="i2c-0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="i2c"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03':
    KERNELS=="AMDI0010:03"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="i2c_designware"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="1000"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="3828620"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="3271200"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/async}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTR{id/vendor}=="2a94", ATTR{id/product}=="a811", ATTR{inhibited}="1"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/80-touchscreen.rules

root@ubuntu-Inspiron-15-3535:~# udevadm control --reload && udevadm trigger
```

Et voilà! The touchscreen is disabled again! This time indefinitely.

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/users/800981/dmitry and https://askubuntu.com/users/136928/dolf-andringa for getting me on the right track. For this answer I figured I'd post every step so that you'd see both how to figure out the values for your system, and how to use them to configure your touchscreen to be disabled.

For more info on udev and sysfs, read these:

- https://unix-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/udev.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev
- http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html
- https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysfs-rules.html

Answer (score -1):

The other solutions do not work for my Lenovo Yago 710. Here's what I do:

- Use `lsmod` to find the module for the touchscreen.

  ```
  lsmod | grep touch
  ```

  For me, it is `hid_multitouch`.
- Disable it temporarily

  ```
  sudo modprobe -r hid_multitouch
  ```

  The `modprobe -r` unloads the kernel module (driver). The touchscreen should be disabled.
- Make it permanent

  Edit `/etc/rc.local` as

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  modprobe -r usbhid
  ```

  In Ubuntu 17.10, you may need to run

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
  ```

  to make `/etc/rc.local` run on startup.