# Enabling and disabling touchscreen with Wayland enabled

Tags: touchscreen, wayland, udev

If you Google how to disable a touchscreen using Wayland, the most common results suggests adding an [udev rule](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011125/19439). In fact, that's how my local install on a HP Inspiron 5379 is setup:

```
~ via  v3.0.2 
❯ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/80-touchscreen.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2494", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

I would, however, like to make this dynamic: the touchscreen is useful from time to time. I see how I could manipulate this dynamically on X11 using `xinput` but I have no idea how Wayland manages input sources.

Is there a way I can toggle an input source on and off for Wayland?

If it's not available from cli or from the GUI but programmatically, I'm OK with the solution as well. I would mind coding a little utility or GNOME Extension to expose this functionality. Any pointers towards the right place in the Wayland will be appreciated!