# How to disable touchscreen?

Tags: 22.04, touchscreen

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Microsoft Surface. The screen is all cracked and the touch screen clicks everywhere randomly, moves the applications and is hard enough to open the terminal, inserting any commands have been very challenging. I tried disabling using xinput but it threw an error about XWayland server.

I'm not too savvy on commands/linux so if someone could assist, taking into consideration that I'm a newbie I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Workaround till someone writes a proper answer. Follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038248/how-to-disable-touchscreen-permanently?rq=1, and switch to X.Org from Wayland (you can choose X.Org session instead of the Wayland session in the login screen). https://askubuntu.com/a/1347522/124466

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/927022/how-can-i-disable-touchscreen-while-using-wayland?rq=1